# jsTree open_all only showing last item in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I am relatively new to working with jQuery and jsTree. In my application I call an API, and then want to display the resulting JSON using jsTree. For my sample I am using this fake API call http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?userId=1

However, when the page loads, only the last item in the array is "open" and if I click on other items then it just shows the data from the last item. Here's a stripped down version: http://jsfiddle.net/7saL0t83/ and here is a screenshot of the phenomenon that I am experiencing

[image]

**HTML**:

```
 <div id="jstree">
 <ul>
     <li>[List]: 
        <ul>
            <li id="userId" value="1">
                userId: 1
            </li>
            <li id="id" value="1">
                id: 1
            </li>
            <li id="title" value="&quot;sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit&quot;">
                title: sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit
            </li>
            <li id="body" value="&quot;quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto&quot;">
                body: quia et suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>[List]: 
        <ul>
            <li id="userId" value="1">
                userId: 1
            </li>
            <li id="id" value="2">
                id: 2
            </li>
            <li id="title" value="&quot;qui est esse&quot;">
                title: qui est esse
            </li>
            <li id="body" value="&quot;est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla&quot;">
                body: est rerum tempore vitae sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </ul> 
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree( {
        "core" : {
            "animation":0,
            "themes": { "icons" : false, "responsive": true }
        },
        "plugins" :["checkbox","state"]
    })
    .bind("ready.jstree", function (event, data) {
         //open all nodes once the ready event is triggered
        $(this).jstree("open_all");
    });
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        console.log(data.selected);
    });
});
```

If I view the HTML source code of the page, all the data is there, so **why does it only open the last item in the array?** Also when clicking on other array items why does it show the data from the last one?

Thanks!

[(my code on jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7saL0t83/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicated IDs - jstree can not parse the structure properly. jstree does not allow for duplicated IDs inside one tree (also keep in mind, you should not duplicate IDs even on document level).

Either remove the ID attribute on each LI node, or make sure they are unique inside the tree.